# Orthogonal complement of arbitrary intersection of Hilbert subspaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, set-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ a Hilbert space, and $\mathcal C$ an arbitrary set of closed subspaces of $H$. Is it true that
$$\left( \bigcap_{Z\in \mathcal C}Z\right)^\perp = \overline{\sum_{Z\in \mathcal C} Z^\perp}$$
where $\sum$ means finite sums of elements in the terms.
The inclusion $\supset$ is clear, so I really am interested in $\subset$.
I have found a similar question asked here:
[Orthogonal complements of intersections of closed subspaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/204740/orthogonal-complements-of-intersections-of-closed-subspaces)

But my question is more general than this. I know it is true in finite dimensions. Also, in the thread above Jochen Wengenroth claims it is true for finite $\mathcal C$, but I do not understand the argument. What about countable $\mathcal C$? Uncountable $\mathcal C$?
Does the situation become easier if we assume $\mathcal C$ totally ordered by inclusion?

I don't know how to approach this so really any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow! Dosn't the inclusion you want follow from the fact that the closure of a vector subspace $V$ can be otained by taking the orthogonal complement twice?

Comment: To add some detail to Jochen's comment: in general $\overline{L(A)}=A^{\perp\perp}$, so the RHS of your identity is $(\bigcup Z^{\perp})^{\perp\perp}=(\bigcap Z^{\perp\perp})^{\perp}=LHS$. Here we use $(\bigcup A_j)^{\perp}=\bigcap A_j^{\perp}$, which is clear from the definition of the orthogonal complement.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!